# "uses a non-entity [class java.lang.Double] as target entity in the relationship attribute", what do I do wrong?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, glassfish, persistence, double

I cannot run my project because I get this error:

```
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [RekeningAdministratiePU] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7250] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: [class domain.Regio] uses a non-entity [class java.lang.Double] as target entity in the relationship attribute [field wegCategoriePrijzen].
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [RekeningAdministratiePU] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7250] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: [class domain.Regio] uses a non-entity [class java.lang.Double] as target entity in the relationship attribute [field wegCategoriePrijzen].
```

My entity class looks like this

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
private String naam;
@OneToMany(cascade= { CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.REMOVE})
private Collection<Locatie> locaties;
@OneToMany(cascade= { CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.REMOVE})
private Collection<Double> autoCategorieMutaties;
@OneToMany(cascade= { CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.REMOVE})
private Collection<Double> wegCategoriePrijzen;
private Double binnenrijTarief;
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The target of a @`OneToMany` mapping must be a valid JPA entity. In your case, the class `Double` is most assuredly not an entity class, hence the error message. If you simply want to store collections of values, consider using @`ElementCollection` instead.

```
@ElementCollection
private Collection<Double> wegCategoriePrijzen;
```

Comment: Theoretically yes, but keep in mind that certain providers (like Hibernate) cannot map multiple Lists within the same entity object. So its safer to go with Collections or Sets.